# Calling function from Fortran DLL with Char as parameter

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes, cffi

I'm trying to call a function (bubblesort) from a 3rd party Fortran DLL with Python. My problem is passing a char to the function. I got it working with cffi as shown below, but I want to use ctypes.
The cffi version:

```
import numpy as np
import cffi as cf

ffi=cf.FFI()
lib=ffi.dlopen(r"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DLL20DDS")
ffi.cdef("""void M01CAF( double rv[], const int *m1, const int *m2, 
        const wchar_t *order, int *ifail);""")

m1 = 1
m1 = ffi.new("int*", m1)
m2 = 16
m2 = ffi.new("int*", m2)
order = ffi.new('wchar_t *', "A")
rvx = np.array([1.3, 5.9, 4.1, 2.3, 0.5, 5.8, 1.3, 6.5, 
                2.3, 0.5, 6.5, 9.9, 2.1, 1.1, 1.2, 8.6], dtype=float, order='F')
rv = ffi.cast("double* ", rvx.__array_interface__['data'][0])
ifail = 0
ifail = ffi.new('int*', ifail)

lib.M01CAF(rv, m1, m2, order, ifail)
print(rvx)
```

Output:

```
[0.5 0.5 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.3 2.1 2.3 2.3 4.1 5.8 5.9 6.5 6.5 8.6 9.9]
```

Now my ctypes version:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct
flib = ct.WinDLL('C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DLL20DDS.dll')
func = getattr(flib, "M01CAF")
func.restype = None

m1 = (ct.c_int32)(1)
m2 = (ct.c_int32)(16)
ifail = ct.c_int32(0)
rv = np.array([1.3, 5.9, 4.1, 2.3, 0.5, 5.8, 1.3, 6.5, 
                2.3, 0.5, 6.5, 9.9, 2.1, 1.1, 1.2, 8.6], dtype=ct.c_double, order='F')

order = 'A'
order = ct.c_wchar_p(order)

func.argtypes = (np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ct.c_double, shape=(m2.value,)), 
                ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), 
                ct.c_wchar_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32))

func(rv, m1, m2, order, ifail)
```

Error Message:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0xFFFFFFFC
```

______________________________________________________
A problem I have with cffi is: When I call the function again it does not sort the array. I need to restart my kernel in order to get the right result:

```
rvx = np.array([1.3, 5.9, 4.1, 2.3, 0.5, 5.8, 1.3, 6.5, 
                2.3, 0.5, 6.5, 9.9, 2.1, 1.1, 1.2, 8.6], dtype=float, order='F')
rv = ffi.cast("double* ", rvx.__array_interface__['data'][0])
lib.M01CAF(rv, m1, m2, order, ifail)
print(rvx)
```

Output:

```
[1.3 5.9 4.1 2.3 0.5 5.8 1.3 6.5 2.3 0.5 6.5 9.9 2.1 1.1 1.2 8.6]
```

______________________________________________________
Right now I'm using Spyder with Python 3.8.3 32bit on Win10 64bit.

Comment: Just FYI the NAG routine M01CAF is based on quicksort, not bubble sort. Also have you tried asking the NAG technical support? When you paid for the library you became eligible for this.

Comment: And, if this is the NAG M01CAF, then NAG provides a Python interface to the library which may be worth considering.

Comment: I don't have your Fortran library, but your code works correctly with a C-equivalent `__stdcall` 32-bit DLL function with the same signature as your `ffi.cdef` above.

Comment: Please provide more specific details on the Fortran procedure.  Is it the NAG routine?

Comment: @MarkTolonen good to know, then NAG might behave somehow different.

Comment: @IanH right now I'm trying to implement my routines in VB, because it seems like it behaves more like you would expect. One weird thing is, that in VB the datatype I need to use is Long (64bit) and in Python it is 32bit integers.

Comment: Does `ffi.new("int*", m1)` return the same type of object as `(ct.c_int32)(1)`.  I'm guessing that it doesn't, which is why the code is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved every problem by passing the length of the char as a regular integer (not pointer) after the pointer of the char itself. The same is necessary for CFFI.

```
## CTYPES
import ctypes as ct
flib = ct.WinDLL('C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DLL20DDS.dll')
func = getattr(flib, "M01CAF")
func.restype = None

m1 = (ct.c_int32)(1)
m2 = (ct.c_int32)(16)
ifail = ct.c_int32(0)
rv = np.array([1.3, 5.9, 4.1, 2.3, 0.5, 5.8, 1.3, 6.5, 
                2.3, 0.5, 6.5, 9.9, 2.1, 1.1, 1.2, 8.6], dtype=ct.c_double, order='F')

order = ct.c_wchar_p('A')
func.argtypes = (np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ct.c_double, shape=(m2.value,)), 
                ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32), 
                ct.c_wchar_p, ct.c_int32, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int32))

print("BEFORE:")
print(rv)

func(rv, m1, m2, order, 1, ifail)

print("AFTER:")
print(rv)
```